# Angular universal + pwa ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'ngsw_worker.es6.js.map'

Tags: angular, angular-universal, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I've set up an universal and pwa app.

Is there a way to fix this error ?

You can see a DEMO (the first push :) ) https://blogial-client.herokuapp.com/

SERVER SIDE CONSOLE

```
ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'ngsw_worker.es6.js.map'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'ngsw_worker.es6.js.map'
```

CHROME CONSOLE

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
```

### UPDATE

I worked it out with

```
ng add @angular/pwa --project *project-name*
```

I forgot the app name :(

Answer (score 1):

I removed `"//# sourceMappingURL=ngsw_worker.es6.js.map"` from `dist/appname/ngsw-worker.js` and it's working.

It seems a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but with angular 6 I've not ngsw-worker.js  file in my dist folder both server and browser

Answer (score 1):

All the above didn´t work for me.
What did work is to "unregister" the service worker on the browser.
It seems that a previous service worker for an app on the same url:port was the problem.

[image]